# How can I configure Consul for k8S in IPVS mode

Tags: kubernetes, consul

I'm use helm installed consul to k8s , but my server is having problems using it
So .Please tell me how to solve it

```bash
[root@master ~]# kubectl logs -n wrs pod/config-server-7b64695cc8-b8c4j -c consul-connect-inject-init
2022-06-15T14:12:18.679Z [INFO]  Registered service has been detected: service=config-server-service
2022-06-15T14:12:18.680Z [INFO]  Registered service has been detected: service=config-server-service-sidecar-proxy
2022-06-15T14:12:18.680Z [INFO]  Connect initialization completed
==> Error setting up traffic redirection rules: failed to run command: /sbin/iptables -t nat -N CONSUL_PROXY_INBOUND, err: exit status 3, output: modprobe: can't change directory to '/lib/modules': No such file or directory
iptables v1.8.7 (legacy): can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

environment:

```
kubernetes v1.23.6 
proxy mode ipvs(not ip_tables)
helm 3.9.0
hashicorp/consul:1.12.0
hashicorp/consul-k8s-control-plane:0.44.0
CentOS Linux release 8.5.2111
Linux master 5.4.198-1.el8.elrepo.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jun 14 07:38:21 EDT 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I was able to get my service running but not working by executing the following command

```bash
sudo modprobe ip_tables
```

Answer (score 0):

Short term solution run modprobe iptables_nat in all worker nodes as root user which will load the module into kernel.

Long term solution you need to use cni based solution and you can check https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/integrations/consul-connect

Comment: Thanks.
I asked consul community and their answer was:
https://www.consul.io/docs/k8s/helm#v-connectinject-transparentproxy
Set this to ```false```
It works!